# querySelectorAll NodeList is undefined

Tags: javascript

In this code fragment, the questions array is blank, which is my first problem. I believe that the 'ol li' selector should select all list items in ordered lists. And second, even if I have an array (currently commented out), I am unable to add an id to it, shown on the first line of code within the for loop.

```
function setUp()
{
    var questions = document.querySelectorAll('ol li');
    /*var questions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];*/
    for (var x = 0; x < questions.length; x++)
    {
        questions[x].id = x + 'phrase';
        onmousedown(showEnglish(questions));
        onmouseup(showFrench(questions));
        onmouseover.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }
}

function showEnglish()
{
    var phraseNumber = parseInt(parent.questions.id);
    document.getElementsById(phraseNumber).innerHTML = english[phraseNumber];
    english[phraseNumber].style.fontStyle = 'italic';
    english[phraseNumber].style.color = 'rgb(191,22,31)';
}
```

Comment: I don't think querySelectorAll will ever return undefined. Perhaps if its an invalid selector but even then I think it throws an error. If it finds nothing it returns an empty NodeList.

Comment: try, `document.querySelectorAll('ol > li')`

Comment: You're sure it's not just the total lack of defined arguments in `showEnglish`, and the fact that `questions` is defined outside that functions scope.

Comment: Does passing in questions when calling showEnglish not matter here?

Answer (score 0):

**document.querySelectorAll('ol li')** will select all the list items in ordered list. You need to explain when are you calling the function **setUp**. If you call this function before these elements are rendered in the DOM, it is possible that the array will be empty.

I did not understand the second part of your question. You said that you are using the following array

```
 questions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

and trying to add an id to it?

If yes then it will throw an error. The reason being on iterating through questions array, the elements you get **questions[x]** is a string and then you are assigning **questions[x].id** to some value. You will get an error as **questions[x]** is a string not an object.

Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Sorry, that array was just used to make sure I could get the loop to start. document.querySelectorAll('ol li') is what I am using. I have windows.onload = setUp() as my first line in the page. Is this too early? querySelectorAll makes an object list correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me if you are doing that. The point is  you need to check two things - 1. Log the value of document.querySelectorAll('ol li') to check if the array is empty or not. 2. In case it is empty, check how the list elements are added on the HTML document. In case, it is not, please check showEnglish and showFrench functions. They could have some issue like check **parent.questions.id**